# Why is this java input validation loop not working

Tags: java

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   //this program test input validation yes or no program

public class Fool
 {
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
    String input;
    char first;
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter yes or no ");
         input=keyboard.nextLine();
        first=input.charAt(0);
        System.out.print(first);
         while( first !='y' || first !='n')
          {
        System.out.println("please enter yes or no");
          }

       }
   }
```

What is trying to get the program to is that the user has to remain in the while loop if the user does not put in yes or no.

Comment: Think about that while condition logically, it will always be true.

Comment: The while should contain `input=keyboard.nextLine();`. Otherwise, first stays the same forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this to

```
while( first !='y' || first !='n') {
        System.out.println("please enter yes or no");
}
```

this

```
while( first !='y' && first !='n') {
        System.out.println("please enter yes or no");
}
```

because `(first !='y' || first !='n')` is always true.

if `first =='y'` then `first !='n'` is true

if `first =='n'` then `first !='y'` is  true.

so while condition is always true
what you need is not `||` but `&&` [and ]

Comment: Huh I though the logic would while first does not equal y or first does not equal n, oh I see the or statement needs only one statement to be true so if someone puts in no, then first will not equal 'y' and thus the loop will start.

Comment: Maybe this helps or maybe confuses you more: `while( first !='y' && first !='n') ` is equivalent to `while(!(first =='y' || first =='n'))` and I find the latter more readable as it's more like how you describe the condition in English.

Comment: Yes that is Demorgans logicc law

Answer (score 1):

```
while( first !='y' || first !='n') is always true.
```

Replace your code with:

```
while( first !='y' && first !='n')
```

Answer (score 1):

`while( first !='y' || first !='n')` is always true.
As OR operation works as follows

### condition 1 condition 2 result

TRUE              TRUE    TRUE

TRUE              FALSE   TRUE

FALSE             TRUE    TRUE

FALSE             FALSE   FALSE

In your case one condition will be always true, therefore it enters in while loop everytime
While AND operation works as follows

### condition 1    condition 2 result

TRUE              TRUE    TRUE

TRUE              FALSE   FALSE

FALSE             TRUE    FALSE

FALSE             FALSE   FALSE

so instead of using OR try using AND
e.g. `while( first !='y' && first !='n')`

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to

```
boolean b=false;
while(b==false){
    if(first !='y' || first !='n'){
        System.out.println("please enter yes or no");
    } else {
        b=true;
    }
}
```